$X\in L^{\infty,p},Y\in L^{2,q},prove \int_{0}^{t} XY_{s}dB_{s}$ is martingale
$L^{\infty,p}$ is X is progressively measurable and $E[\max_{0\le t\le T} \left | X_{t} \right |^{p} ]<\infty$
$L^{2,q}$ is Y is progressively measurable and $E[(\int_{0}^{T}\left | Y_{t} \right |^{2}dt)^{q/2}]<\infty$
Filtration is natural filtration by BM.p,q be conjugates.
Jianfeng Zhang give a problem to prove that  $\int_{0}^{t} XY_{s}dB_{s}$ is martingale in his book BSDE at page 58.
I first want to prove it by ito isometric.
prove $E[\int_{0}^{T} (XY_{s})^{2}ds]<\infty$ to prove it is a$L^{2} martingale$
but i can't prove it. maybe is it not a $L^{2} martingale$ ?is it a $L^{1} martingale$ ?
how to solve this problem

Let $Z_t:=\int_0^t X_sY_s\,dB_s$, a continuous local martingale.
By the Burkholder-Gundy-Davis inequality there is a constant $C$ such that:
$$
\eqalign{
E\left[\max_{0\le t\le T}|Z_t|\right]
&\le C\cdot E\left[\left(\int_0^T X_s^2Y_s^2\,ds\right)^{1/2}\right]\cr
&\le C\cdot E\left[\max_{0\le t\le T}|X_t|\cdot\left(\int_0^T Y_s^2\,ds\right)^{1/2}\right]\cr
}
$$
Finally apply  Hölder's inequality to deduce that $\max_{0\le t\le T}|Z_t|$ is integrable. It follows that the local martingale $(Z_t)_{0\le t\le T}$ is a martingale.

thank you,i ignore the bdg ineguality
