Prove that a stochastic integral is a martingale
Let $p,q$ be conjugates such that $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$. Suppose that $$\mathbf{E}[\underset{t\in [0,T]}{\sup}|X_t|^p]<+\infty$$ and $$\mathbf{E}[(\int_0^T|Y_t|^2 dt)^{q/2}]<+\infty$$ I am trying to prove that $\int_0^tX_sY_sdB(s)$ is an uniformly integrable martingale.
My clue is to prove that $\mathbf{E}\int_0^T X_t^2Y_t^2dt<+\infty$, but unfortunately this seems not to be true.

Let $M$ denote the local martingale $M_t=\int_0^t X_sY_s\,dB_s$. You can use the Burkholder-Gundy-Davis inequality to show that
$$
\mathbf{E}\left[\sup_{0\le t\le T}|M_t|\right]<\infty
$$
for each $T>0$. [See my answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4929743/x-in-l-infty-p-y-in-l2-q-prove-int-0t-xy-sdb-s-is-martingale/4930621#4930621 .]
This is more than enough to deduce that $M$ is a true martingale.
